# C#/ASP.NET: HREF Path not updating after code-behind change

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I'm working on a website for my company that will allow us to house and distribute .XML and .HTM Perfmon Templates. The site consists of a creator tool that is used to create the templates and a repository where the templates are stored. When a user hits the repository site and chooses to view either XML or HTM Templates, the  the page looks in a directory (~/Perfmon Templates/) and lists out all of files of the type that the user specified. It creates a hyperlink to the file and parses the file to list the counters that are included in the template. This is all working without issue on my local machine. Yesterday, I published the website to an IIS7 server running ASP.NET 4.6.

After publishing, while testing the site, I found that the hyperlinks in the repository were no longer working. This was because the path changed ever so slightly from ~/Perfmon Templates/ to ~/Perfmon/Perfmon Templates. So I opened up the C# code behind for the repository webpage and changed the relative path for the hyperlink to reflect the path changes. After copying the .cs code behind file and the .aspx page file back up to the server, I ran the test again and found no change in the hyperlink path.

My first thought, at this point, was that the C# file must be getting cached somewhere so I tried a CTRL+F5 on the browser to see if that corrected the issue. It did not.

So I went back to the local copy that I have on my machine and tried to run the updated page in debug mode on my local machine. I set break points where the hyperlinks are created and insured that the relative path on the hyperlinks was pointing to the updated location. I then started debugging but found that the site was not processing my breakpoints at all regardless of whether I chose to start debugging from the Debug menu or if I clicked the Play button to start it.

After that didn't work, I tried commenting out all of the lines of C# code that control the creation of the hyperlinks and restarted Debugging. To my shock and surprise, the old hyperlink path was still present on the page.

It seems like the page is not even reading the C# code-behind file, but I know it has to be getting the code from somewhere and that code-behind file is the only location in my solution where the hyperlink path is even mentioned.

Here is the code from the C# code behind file that controls the creation of the hyperlink. I'm not sure it will help resolve the problem though since I have commented almost all of it out at one point and it still didn't make a difference.

```
HyperLink fileLink = new HyperLink();
        fileLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Perfmon/Perfmon Templates/" + f.Name.ToString();
        fileLink.Text = f.Name.ToString();
        fileLink.Visible = true;
        fileLink.Style.Add("color", "#111111");
        fileLink.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");

        string perfCounterList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, counters);
        string perfCounters = Regex.Replace(perfCounterList, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />");
        //dt.Rows.Add(Count, "<a href='/Perfmon/Perfmon Templates/" + f.Name.ToString() + "'>" + f.Name.ToString() + "</a>", perfCounters);
        dt.Rows.Add(Count, fileLink, perfCounters);
```

Can anyone please point me to where I am going wrong? I've checked the web.config file to insure that Debugging is enabled. I've tried the CTRL + F5 trick to see if it was browser cache that was interfering. Neither of those things seem to help at all. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution? Deploy also the new dll builded.

Comment: You have **Web application** project. You have to rebuild the application and upload `.dll` from `bin` folder. If it were **Website** project then it would be enough to upload `.aspx` and `.cs` files.

Comment: Thanks guys, that wasn't quite the whole answer that I needed but it was enough information to get me on the right path to resolve the issue. Turns out, it was my fault (surprise!). I changed the build output directory and so whenever I would rebuild the solution, the changes weren't reflected because the build output files were located somewhere else. I changed the build output directory back to the default, but that broke Application Insights. In the end, I had to create a new project and copy all of the files from the old project into the new one. Afterward, everything seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by changing the build output directory and not moving the build files from the new build location to the server.